# Constructed CSS link in Razor view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a lot of copies of this in my codebase:

```
@if (Context.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='~/Styles/FrontEnd.css' type='text/css' 
}
else
{
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/public/css/FrontEnd-min.css' type='text/css' />
}
```

And this was irritating me, so I wanted to pull that if and the duplication into a helper method, which I did:

```
public static MvcHtmlString IncludeDebugAwareStylesheet(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string debugFileName, string liveFileName)
{
    var styleSheetWrapperFormat = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='{0}' type='text/css' />";
    var debugInclude = string.Format(styleSheetWrapperFormat, debugFileName);
    var liveInclude = string.Format(styleSheetWrapperFormat, liveFileName);
    var isDebug = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled;
    return new MvcHtmlString(isDebug ? debugInclude : liveInclude );
}
```

But now the CSS files aren't being recognised.
As far as I can tell, in the original, the `~` is getting removed, but in my new code, it isn't?

Why is this? Do I need to tell Razor to "Process" the URL in some manner?

Comment: Why not just use bundles and layouts to deal with this for you? Bundles to minify automatically on release build and layouts to only reference the css in one file.

Comment: Agree that would be ideal, but this is a Legacy code base, so that's not a viable change at this stage. :(

Comment: You might have more luck using a tagbuilder, but otherwise I can't see anything obvious. Other than the return statement references `debugHtml` not `debugInclude`.

Comment: @ThomasBoby thanks, fixed (Actual scenario is more complex, so I simplified the demo code down and missed a variable name change)

Comment: @ThomasBoby EDIT: nvm found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.generatecontenturl.aspx) to resolve the project-relative reference.

Try:

```
public static MvcHtmlString IncludeDebugAwareStylesheet(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string debugFileName, string liveFileName)
{
    var styleSheetWrapperFormat = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='{0}' type='text/css' />";
    var debugInclude = string.Format(styleSheetWrapperFormat, UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(debugFileName, htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext));
    var liveInclude = string.Format(styleSheetWrapperFormat, UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(liveFileName, htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext));
    var isDebug = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled;
    return new MvcHtmlString(isDebug ? debugInclude : liveInclude );
}
```

This is because `~` means "project-root" in ASP.Net/MVC. In your .cshtml files the Razor view engine is automatically compiling those references into a the correct relative url, but your HtmlHelper extension is currently just putting the string in as-is, rather than resolving the reference first.

Comment: Yep that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The other solution I came across, which is doesn't answer this literal question, but is the better solution for my scenario.

The altenative is to use `Styles.Render(fileName)`
It's in the `System.Web.Optimisations` Nuget Package/namespace, and basically does all the work for you.

But it wouldn't work if you *actually* needed to generate the tag by hand.